# How to implement copy constructor when working with malloc()

Tags: c++, malloc, copy-constructor

When the instance of `Foo` is created, the object `oMyClass` is passed and its copy constructor called.
MyClass has a void pointer as member that is pointing to memory which is freed in the dtor.
How do I implement the copy constructor correctly to avoid Segmentation faults when  `free()` is called twice on the same memory?

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClass oMyClass();

    Foo oFoo(oMyClass);
} 

class MyClass
{
    public:
         MyClass()
         {
          struct foo *pFoo;
          buf = malloc(sizeof(*pFoo));
         }

         MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass& oMyClass)
         {
            printf("Copyconstructor called\n");
            //?
         }
         MyClass::~MyClass()
         {
          struct foo *pFoo = (struct foo *)buf;
          free(pFoo);
         }

    private:
      void* buf;

    };


/*Foo.h*/

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( MyClass& oMyClass);
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
private:
    MyClass m_oMyClass;
};

/*Foo.cpp*/
Foo::Foo( MyClass& oMyClass): m_oMyClass(oMyClass)
{

}

Foo::Foo()
{
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `void*` and `malloc`?

Comment: Actually I am using libmtd and `void*` is actually `libmtd_t`. `libmtd_open()` is called in the constructor and allocates the memory. In The dtor `libmtd_close()` is called to free the memory. I thought it would be more readable this way.

Comment: `MyClass oMyClass();` is NOT an instantiation of `MyClass`. Use `MyClass oMyClass;` instead.

Comment: @tzippy: Well, if `buf` represents a resource, then you should wrap it in another object (or use a reference counted pointer like `std::shared_ptr`) -- you don't want to copy the filehandle everywhere!

Answer (score 5):

Don't write a copy-constructor at all (see [Rule of Zero](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-zero.html)).

Instead, rely on smart pointers with custom deleters to do the resource management for you. A `unique_ptr` will give you movable ownership, a `shared_ptr` will give you shared ownership:

```
void* data = malloc(sizeof(*pFoo));
// either
std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> foo(data, free);
// or
std::shared_ptr<void> foo(data, free);
```

Only if you really want to perform a deep copy of the enclosed data do you need to write a copy constructor (but you can still have the `free` being executed by a `const unique_ptr` in that case).

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the data (or keep a reference count and only free the data when the last object referencing it is destroyed -- but this is almost certainly not what you want if the data is mutable).

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass& oMyClass)
{
    buf = malloc(sizeof(foo));

    memcpy(buf, oMyClass.buf, sizeof(foo));
    // or new(buf) foo(*reinterpret_cast<foo*>(oMyClass.buf));
}
```

If you use the normal `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`, you'd get copy constructors of `foo` for free...

Answer (score 1):

When you copy construct here, you need to create your own way of constructing the item.

The "default" is to simply copy the item to the new item. That's what's giving you the seg-fault, because when this is copied normally the pointer to foo will be the same in two places. Then, when destructing, you free the same memory twice.

So, in your copy constructor, you need to allocate new memory, and copy the contents of the memory as well:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass& oMyClass)
{
    buf = malloc(sizeof(foo));
    memcpy(buf, oMyClass.foo, sizeof(foo));            
    printf("Copyconstructor called\n");
    //?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the question is here - what do you want to happen?

You can either share the memory between the two classes or make a copy of the memory.

## Sharing the memory

Ideally use a class such as [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) as that will automatically do reference counting for you. If you would like to do reference counting yourself, you will have to use the atomic intrinsics available in your compiler and have an integer malloced that will track the reference count.

## Copying the memory

You can use `std::memcpy` to copy the memory into a newly allocated piece of memory:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass& other)
    : buf(malloc(sizeof(*buf)) {
  if (!buf) {
    throw std:bad_alloc();
  }
  std::memcpy(buf, other.buf, sizeof(*buf));
}
```